# Add a function to Matlab path

Tags: function, matlab, strsplit

I am trying to add the `strsplit` function to my MATLAB path, but I don't know how to do it.

Link : [strsplit function](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4615-split-delimiter-separated-strings-into-a-matrix/content/strsplit.m)

I am trying to use the function for my work, but somehow that function does not exist in my version of MATLAB that i currently have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strsplit` is not a matlab function, in the sense that it does not come with MATLAB, your link is to the mathworks file exchange which is a community of MATLAB users.

You can use the dialog box in the "File"->"Set Path" menu to add the file to your path.
This is assuming you have actually the file and for some reason it is not on your path.

Comment: I did try Set Path, but when i ran strsplit, it does not exist in the path. What i did was, i created a new folder inside `toolbox` folder and then saved the code from the link i specified above as .m file and added that m file inside the new folder i created. From there, i went into Set Path and just added the new folder to it. There's an option for me to save the path. Should i do it ?

Comment: My apologies. I did make it work. Had to just save the path once i have added it. Thank you for the solution

Comment: I understand how to add a folder, but can you add only a function inside a folder? When using `addpath(example_path\example_script.m)` MATLAB indicates the folder does not exist or is not a folder.

Answer (score 2):

From the information you provide and from Matlab's documentation `strsplit` is not an intrinsic Matlab function.  So the question for you is *Where have you installed the source of the strsplit function ?*  When you've answered that for yourself use the `File | Set Path` menu.

Comment: Like i explained to @Ali, i have created a new folder inside the `toolbox/matlab` folder called 'strsplit' and then saved the m file inside there.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, as others have said, you need to make sure the file actually exists in some directory on your computer.  If you need to use this file in a script, you can use the following line to add this file's particular location to your path.

```
path(path,'c:\example\fileishere');
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to confirm that it is in the path, try to run `which` to discover where it is located

```
 which('strsplit')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not seeing the problem.

1. So you download the function?
2. And with matlab you changed in the directory where it is. Then it's in your current path. Then it's in your path as long as you are in that dir. Or you use the "add to path" from the file menu.