# Undefined function or method 'split' for input arguments of type 'cell' in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, split, cell

I wrote a code in which i would like to split a number of rows along each column that it is represented in based on a delimiter. I wrote a for loop in which it does it for me.

`Pdbindex` is a cell array, where my values are stored that i am trying to split with a delimiter, a colon (:).

[image]

```
for i = pdbindex(:,1)

    clean2_pdb = split(':', pdbindex);

end
```

However, it threw me an error stating, `Undefined function or method 'split' for input arguments of type 'cell'.`.

I don't know to solve this.

Please advise.

**Update:**

I have also posted another question of using `strsplit` function. A different problem pops up.

Link : [Strsplit function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366887/do-a-string-split-for-more-than-one-row-in-matlab)

Comment: It's self explaining. So do you have the function split? If so what does it take for input?

Comment: Yes i do, it exists in the path. It basically, first objec takes in the delimiter that you're trying to split from, and the second object takes in the cell array in which it contains the values that you're trying to split from.

Comment: Then I'm just guessing - but it sure sounds like split takes strings and not cell. But maybe you can clarify what split you use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add a function to Matlab path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364062/add-a-function-to-matlab-path)

Comment: From the title and description, the problem is that the `split` function isn't on the path. You've already asked how to add functions to the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such function called `split`. What you want is:

```
for i = 1:size(pdbIndex, 1)
    clean2_pdb = regexp(pdbIndex{i,1}, ':', 'split');
end
```

Comment: I'm using MATLAB version 2010b and they do have split as a function in the path. Back to your solution, I don't want the entire row to be concatenated. I want each to split all of the rows in the first column along each of their respective column. Eg. first column in the first row will have 153, second column 154 and so on.

Comment: Please be clearer with your questions. Your question is "split returns an error". The answer is "there's no such function. use something else".

Comment: My apologies, i don't know why there's no such function for you, but it is to me. However, i have manage to do using regular expressions and call out a few more parameters. This has solve all of the confusion that I have been having.

Answer (score 0):

Another way can be accessing the cell data as a string and then using strsplit func on the cell contents.

```
for i = 1:size(pdbIndex, 1)
clean2_pdb = strsplit(pdbIndex{i},':')
end
```